# UK Citizen need to travel to UK asap but expired passport is getting renewed

Tags: uk, passports

My passport was expired so sent to the UK to get a renewal since I live in the US.

My father has fallen ill so I need to get to the UK asap BUT don't have even my expired passport in my possession since I had to send it to the UK.

Answer (score 25):

You can apply for an [emergency travel document](https://www.gov.uk/emergency-travel-document).  According to the site, it takes about 2 working days.

If that is not fast enough, [call your closest British consulate](https://www.gov.uk/world/usa#/world/emergency-help-for-british-nationals-usa) and ask if they can help sooner.

Comment: Go ahead with these actions but don't be surprised if your new passport arrives first. The last time I renewed my UK passport, it took about a week from dropping off the package at a FedEx office to a DHL delivery person ringing my doorbell.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan before or after Brexit? ;)

Comment: @Cœur I'm going with "before", since, as far as I'm aware, Patricia hasn't been travelling at relativistic velocities with respect the European Union so it's impossible for her to have already done something after an event that is still in the future.